# Multiline Group Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I've searched and searched, but I don't know how I'm doing this wrong. I am trying to obtain the "image name" from each "block" in a text file using Regex in c#. Here's what the text looks like:

```
begin block Block_test
  LowFlight_005_001  strip_id 5
  LowFlight_005_002  strip_id 5
  LowFlight_006_005  strip_id 6
  LowFlight_006_004  strip_id 6
  LowFlight_006_003  strip_id 6
  LowFlight_006_002  strip_id 6
  LowFlight_006_001  strip_id 6
  LowFlight_007_001  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_002  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_003  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_004  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_005  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_011  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_012  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_013  strip_id 7
  LowFlight_007_014  strip_id 7
end block
```

using this regex:

```
begin block Block_test\n(  (?<image>.*?)  (.*?\n))*end block
```

BUT! The named group image is always just the last image, i.e. LowFlight_007_014. How do I select the image from each line. I've tried using the multiline flag and inserting line begins and ends like so:

```
begin block Block_test\n(^  (?<image>.*?)  (.*?$\n))*end block
```

Doesn't help. Help me regex wizards! I created an account just for this. Of course I can grab the whole list of images, split on newline and then clean the string array, but I would love to do it all in regex, for SCIENCE!

Comment: Is the only way to regex the whole block and then regex that regex?

Comment: Reading this: www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: I'm not sure on this, but the \n might not be helping, if it's windows newline convention: \r\n - I'd think you could just remove that, or replace it with .{0-2}
Also, are you using a regex design tool? I use http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: @penguat I was using RegExBuilder, but didn't like how it didn't see the return characters (\r) in my text above (which is why they aren't in my regex expression), so I had removed that. Using the tool you linked and this statement worked how I imagined: begin block Block_test\r\n(  (?<image>.*?)  (.*\r\n))*end block                                                                                                                                   returning a group named "image" with each image name in it! Now to test in actual execution!

Comment: was that a solution then? (in which case I'll write it up!) or is there still a problem?

Comment: Also, are there several of these blocks in the string input? in which case you might need to identify them? If this is the whole file, a much simpler regex would work - something like  ^  (?<image>.*?)  .*$

Comment: @penguat All is good, thank you for your help, I do find the block using "begin block " + StringWithNameOfBlockIWant + @"\r\n(  (?<image>.*?)  (.*\r\n))*end block". After having to search using "site:microsoft.com group class" on google I was able to uncover how the group class works (I understand group collection but there was no links from there leading to actual definitions for group) I was able to see groups have a captures property.

Comment: Continued- Using matches[0].Groups["image"].Captures I am able to see all the images as individual indexes and then just ToString them! Sorry, I am a noob and have been self taught and have been coding c# for about a week. I really appreciate the patience and prompt help!

Comment: You are very welcome - as far as I'm concerned, that's what this site is for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about other lines in the file, or multiple blocks, the simplest regex I can think of will be:

```
new Regex(@"  (?<image>\w*)  ");
```

which will capture multiple matches, each with one "image" group.

If you have to think about multiple blocks in one input, I suspect you will need to use multiple regexes, to split into blocks, and then find images.

If you need to find only the images from lines within blocks, then your answer seems to be in your comment:

```
begin block Block_test\r\n(  (?<image>.*?) (.*\r\n))*end block
```

although you might consider using \w:

```
begin block Block_test\r\n(  (?<image>\w*) (.*\r\n))*end block
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
begin block Block_test(?'body'.*?)end block
```

that capture the test in the named gropu 'body', but remember to specify `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.
Even with the SingleLine option you can use:

```
begin block Block_test(\s+\S+\s+\S+\s\d)+
```

to have a capture for each block.

Comment: Yeah... that gets the body, but I want each individual image, can a named group not be segmented? Or are you suggesting running another regex on body to grab the individual image names?

Comment: @stereotypeaura I upgrated the reply

Answer (score 0):

I would split this task, what about this

```
String Block = "Begin block Block_test\n" +
" LowFlight_005_001  strip_id 5\n" +
" LowFlight_005_002  strip_id 5\n" +
" LowFlight_006_005  strip_id 6\n" +
" LowFlight_006_004  strip_id 6\n" +
" LowFlight_006_003  strip_id 6\n" +
" LowFlight_006_002  strip_id 6\n" +
" LowFlight_006_001  strip_id 6\n" +
"end block";

String[] lines = Regex.Split(Block, @"[\r\n]+");
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\s*(?<image>.*?)\s+(.*?$)");

foreach (String item in lines) {
    if (!(item.StartsWith("Begin") || item.StartsWith("end"))) {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        Match result = reg.Match(item);
        Console.WriteLine(result.Groups["image"]);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```